# Why does a youtube icon show up on facebook?

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

Why does a youtube icon show up on facebook after users on my site make a comment?

For example: http://freeskateboardsticker.com/news/articles.php?articleId=54

If you make a comment on any of the pages on my site, the comments are fine and do what they are supposed to do, but after the user makes a comment and they go to their facebook account to see that comment, there is a YouTube icon next to it.

How to change this?

I have searched and cannot find anyone else with this issue.

Thank You.
James

Comment: How do I get my website icon/thumbnail to show in the comments on the users' facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you don't have any og:image specified for http://freeskateboardsticker.com/news/articles.php?articleId=54

See: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Ffreeskateboardsticker.com%2Fnews%2Farticles.php%3FarticleId%3D54

For issues you should fix.

Comment: Thanks DMCS.  There were 8 Inferred Property Warnings.  I really don't understand them.  I will try to work them out, but do all the og:properties go into meta tags or in the fb: calls on the page?

Comment: they go in the head section.  See http://ogp.me for lots of examples.